# How to style a button with a specific color in React JS

Tags: reactjs, button

I am currently working on a project using React JS, and I have encountered a problem while defining a button using the following code:

```
<Button> Submit </Button>
```

My specific issue is that I would like to give the button a specific color. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this. Could you please provide guidance or suggest a solution to style the button with a custom color in React JS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To set the color attribute for the button correctly in React JS, you should utilize the style property in the following manner:

```
<Button
  style={{backgroundColor: '#228B22',}}
> Submit </Button>
```

By using the `style` attribute and specifying the `backgroundColor` property with the desired color value (in this case, #228B22), the button will be displayed with the specified color.